# SQl error while inserting to a table using java

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to insert a new row to the sql table Customers using the following code:

```
                    String str = "register customer Mark Waid 1234567 389529548 Monthly LilacHaifa "
                    + "1234567891234567 5/2025";
                    String[] tokens = str.trim().split("\\s++");
                    sql = "INSERT INTO Customers " +
                    "(ID, Name, Password, Connected, SubscriptionType, Status, Store Name, CreditCardNumber, Balance, ExpirationDate) "
                    + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                    preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    preparedStmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(tokens[5]));
                    preparedStmt.setString(2, tokens[2] + " " + tokens[3]);
                    preparedStmt.setString(3, tokens[4]);
                    preparedStmt.setInt(4, 1);
                    preparedStmt.setString(5, tokens[6]);
                    preparedStmt.setInt(6, 1);
                    preparedStmt.setString(7, tokens[7]);
                    preparedStmt.setString(8, tokens[8]);
                    preparedStmt.setDouble(9, 0);
                    preparedStmt.setString(10, tokens[9]);
                    preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
```

but I get the following error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Name, CreditCardNumber, Balance, ExpirationDate) VALUES (389529548,'Mark Waid','' at line 1
SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Name, CreditCardNumber, Balance, ExpirationDate) VALUES (389529548,'Mark Waid','' at line 1
SQLState: 42000
VendorError: 1064
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1332)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1604)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1519)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1504)
    at ocsf.LilacServer.handleMessageFromClient(LilacServer.java:297)
    at ocsf.AbstractServer.receiveMessageFromClient(AbstractServer.java:474)
    at ocsf.ConnectionToClient.run(ConnectionToClient.java:219)
```

There is definitely a problem with my query except I cant recognize exactly what it is.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: `Store name` smells as a name for a field

Comment: You probably don't have a column named `Store Name` (with a space in it).

Comment: Rename the column to avoid future problems. E.g. `StoreName`.

Answer (score 2):

`Store Name` column has a space in it, so it should be quoted properly, depending on which database you use.

Eg:

**MS SQL Server**: `[Store Name]`
**Oracle**: `"Store Name"`
**MySQL**: `` `Store Name` ``
**Postgres**: `"Store Name"`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing sql with the below one :-

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Customers " +
      "(ID, Name, Password, Connected, SubscriptionType, Status, `Store Name`, CreditCardNumber, Balance, ExpirationDate) "
      + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ***INSERT*** SQL Query query **Store Name** seems to be the incorrect column name.

Please check the DDL of the table **Customers** , and check the StoreName column in it. It would be good if you paste the **Customers** table DDL in the question.

If its correct then it has to be used with single quotes as ***'Store Name'***, as shown in below code:

```
 sql = "INSERT INTO Customers " +
                    "(ID, Name, Password, Connected, SubscriptionType, Status, 'Store Name', CreditCardNumber, Balance, ExpirationDate) "
                    + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```